# How to properly create KsqlDB stream based on Kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I'm attempting to create a KsqlDB stream (using KSQL CLI) in the following way:

```
CREATE STREAM orders_stream (
    OrderId BIGINT,
    Description VARCHAR
  ) WITH (
    KAFKA_TOPIC = ‘orders’,
    VALUE_FORMAT = 'JSON'
  );
```

I get this error:

```
line 5:19: mismatched input '‘' expecting {'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '-', STRING, INTEGER_VALUE, DECIMAL_VALUE, FLOATING_POINT_VALUE, VARIABLE}
Statement: CREATE STREAM orders_stream (
    Ordered BIGINT,
    Description VARCHAR
  ) WITH (
    KAFKA_TOPIC = ‘orders’,
    VALUE_FORMAT = 'JSON'
  );
Caused by: line 5:19: mismatched input '‘' expecting {'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE',
    '-', STRING, INTEGER_VALUE, DECIMAL_VALUE, FLOATING_POINT_VALUE, VARIABLE}
Caused by: org.antlr.v4.runtime.InputMismatchException
```

I can't seem to find the issue here.
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change ‘orders’ to 'orders' , it works.

ksql> CREATE STREAM orders_stream (

> OrderId BIGINT, Description VARCHAR   )
> WITH (  KAFKA_TOPIC = 'orders', PARTITIONS=1, REPLICAS=1,
> VALUE_FORMAT = 'JSON' );

### Message

### Stream created

ksql>